# How to run airflow, mlflow and minio in docker compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I am trying to use apache airflow with mlflow with minio. The mlflow container is unable to access the postgres container. If I change the container name, it becomes accessible to mlflow but not to airflow. How do I allow both to run on the same postgres connection?

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-my_airflow_image:v1.0}
  #build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${PG_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PG_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=${PG_DATABASE}
    expose:
      - "${PG_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  s3:
    restart: always
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: mlflow_minio
    volumes:
      - ./minio_data:/data
    ports:
      - "${MINIO_PORT}:9000"
      - "${MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT}:9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MINIO_ADDRESS=${MINIO_ADDRESS}
      - MINIO_PORT=${MINIO_PORT}
      - MINIO_STORAGE_USE_HTTPS=${MINIO_STORAGE_USE_HTTPS}
      - MINIO_CONSOLE_ADDRESS=${MINIO_CONSOLE_ADDRESS}
    command: server /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
  
  create_buckets:
    image: minio/mc
    container_name: mlflow_create_buckets
    depends_on:
      - s3
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c '
      sleep 5;
      /usr/bin/mc config host add s3 http://s3:${MINIO_PORT} ${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY} ${MINIO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} --api S3v4;
      [[ ! -z "`/usr/bin/mc ls s3 | grep challenge`" ]] || /usr/bin/mc mb s3/${MLFLOW_BUCKET_NAME};
      /usr/bin/mc policy download s3/${MLFLOW_BUCKET_NAME};
      exit 0;
      '
      
  tracking_server:
    restart: always
    image: ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow
    container_name: mlflow_server
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "${MLFLOW_PORT}:5000"
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://s3:${MINIO_PORT}
      - MLFLOW_S3_IGNORE_TLS=true
    command: 
       - bash 
       - -c
       - '(mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --backend-store-uri postgresql://${PG_USER}:${PG_PASSWORD}@postgres:${PG_PORT}/${PG_DATABASE} --default-artifact-root s3://mlflow)'
    volumes:
    - ${PWD}/include/mlflow/data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:${MLFLOW_PORT}/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3  

 
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      # yamllint disable rule:line-length
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully


  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/sources
  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow
  

volumes:
  minio_data:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

My error:

```
mlflow_server          | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:321: UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
mlflow_server          | * 'schema_extra' has been renamed to 'json_schema_extra'
mlflow_server          |   warnings.warn(message, UserWarning)
mlflow_server          | 2024/02/18 15:58:33 INFO mlflow.store.db.utils: Creating initial MLflow database tables...
mlflow_server          | 2024/02/18 15:58:33 INFO mlflow.store.db.utils: Updating database tables
mlflow_server          | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
mlflow_server          | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
mlflow_server          | 2024/02/18 15:58:33 ERROR mlflow.cli: Error initializing backend store
mlflow_server          | 2024/02/18 15:58:33 ERROR mlflow.cli: Can't locate revision identified by '88344c1d9134'
mlflow_server          | Traceback (most recent call last):
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 251, in _catch_revision_errors
mlflow_server          |     yield
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 459, in _upgrade_revs
mlflow_server          |     for script in reversed(list(revs))
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 813, in iterate_revisions
mlflow_server          |     revisions, heads = fn(
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 1466, in _collect_upgrade_revisions
mlflow_server          |     current_revisions = self.get_revisions(lower)
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 543, in get_revisions
mlflow_server          |     return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 543, in <listcomp>
mlflow_server          |     return sum([self.get_revisions(id_elem) for id_elem in id_], ())
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 566, in get_revisions
mlflow_server          |     return tuple(
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 567, in <genexpr>
mlflow_server          |     self._revision_for_ident(rev_id, branch_label)
mlflow_server          |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 638, in _revision_for_ident
mlflow_server          |     raise ResolutionError(
mlflow_server          | alembic.script.revision.ResolutionError: No such revision or branch '88344c1d9134'
```

However, it works if airflow is using sqlite